# Implementing chat in phonegap app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, websocket, chat

I have to take a technical decision but I'mt not sure.
I have to implement a chat in a Phonegap-App which runs on iOS and Android.

The whole app is based on a Microsoft Azure-Mobile Service, so I have enough server power.

Currently I have identified three ways of implementing such a chat:

- **Websockets**: The app communicates through websockets with the backend which would be done in Node.JS then. Each new message is pushed to the server through that socket, and each message sent by the user is sent back on that channel. My problem is the reliabillity of websockets, especially when we take in consideration that the user walks around, is ones connect to a public WIFI-Hotspot or through GPRS... I had some bad experiences with websockets getting blocked by proxies.
- **Comet / Long Polling**: The app initiates long polling requests and the server keeps checking incoming messages, and when they reach, he answers immediately. Because I'm using NodeJS this is easier, because there is no blocking of threads. But it feels very bad for me to do that, especially with all this new possibillities of HTML5 (Websockets for example, see above)
- **APNS / GCM**: Using the Push Message-Services of each platform to send the informations like that to the device. That means, if the user has the app open in the background the're are incoming messages each whatever seconds (especially in high frequently used chatrooms)

What would you recommend? Have you ever used for example websockets in a mobile Phonegap App?

Comment: Websocket is good but it only support for Android >4.4.

Comment: Thats not really a problem, there are phonegap plugins for older android versions... but what about the connectivity? when user walks around and changes the network from WiFi to GPRS, or when he is connected with a public WiFi Spot which has a proxy which blocks websockets...?

Comment: @iliraga In that case, you'd better use a websocket lib with fallback, like socket.io. The new version is rather good.

Comment: I have chosen to use a commercial service like Pusher which has a nice integration into the Azure Environement and uses a long polling fallback if websockets are not supported or currently not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decied to use PubNub, as they provide a very good implementation for Mobile Clients. Instead of using Websocket, they use a battery-friendly long polling.